# Django models relationship collision

Tags: django, model, relational-database, relationship

I'm django learner and i have problem with django relationship concept.
I have written two models that have relations with single source model (UserProfile).but one of them does not work properly.The Message class work fine with it's two fields (sender,receiver),but the other class(Class) lead to

> programing error:relation "CEA_class" already exists

where CEA is my app name.I really prefer to have two different field for the class and don't join them as single field.What I'm suppose to do with it?

> class Message ---->that work fine

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,blank=False,related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,blank=False,related_name="receiver")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    priority = models.BigIntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_LIST,default=1)
```

> class Class ---->that lead to error

```
class Class(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)    
    students = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,blank=True,related_name="students")
    master = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,blank=True,related_name="master")
```

Here is my whole UserProfile class

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(User, 
    related_name='UserProfile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field=models.CharField(max_length=20,default="ce")
    userPhoto=models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/',blank=True)
    Type=models.BigIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE,default=2)
    gender=models.BigIntegerField(choices=GENDER_TYPE,default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username




#The decorator can also takes extra arguments which are passed onto the 
   signal
   @receiver(post_save,sender=User)
   def create_or_update_UserProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.UserProfile.save()
```

I have an error in my admin page as below:
.

> ProgrammingError at /admin/CEA/class/
>
> column CEA_class.master_id does not exist LINE 1: ...time",
>   "CEA_class"."day", "CEA_class"."location", "CEA_class...

Comment: I don't think the problem is because of Django, I think all you need to do is drop the table and run `migrate` again. Which database are you using?? PostgreSQL?

Comment: and try to use some other name except Class, its confusing to use a inbuilt keyword as your table name

Comment: Yes i use postrgreSQL,I tried flushing the database or migrate the data again but didn't work.I tried reset migration as exist on the web like(https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html) but i have problem yet.

Comment: It leads to ProgrammingError:column CEA_class.master_id does not exist    when i tried to edit Class by admin page.

Comment: And when i delete the field "master",everything works fine

Comment: You included Class and Message. Where is UserProfile defined?

Comment: UserProfile work fine with Message but here you are.                                                               class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='UserProfile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field=models.CharField(max_length=20,default="ce")
..................................................................................................@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_or_update_UserProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.UserProfile.save()

Comment: It is always helpful to think about what changes you made before the error ocurred? or is this your first migration? Try deleting all your migration files except the init file, then makemigration -> migrate.

Comment: Every time after "python manage.py makemigrations" i have error.Even before migrate command.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a while ago and found some references including in the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name), but I'm actually still not quite sure why this is needed as the underlying SQL structure doesn't (as far as I can tell in looking at my own database) show the variance in related_name - it appears to be an internal Django issue rather than an actual SQL issue. In any case, when you have more than one field related to the same other model within a table then all except one have to have something referencing the class in order to get Django to keep things straight. It is often cleanest to add class to ALL the related_names within a model that has the problem for consistency, though I have checked my own code and sometimes I do that, sometimes I don't:

```
students = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,blank=True,related_name="%(class)s_students")
master = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,blank=True,related_name="%(class)s_master")
```

Comment: It was so helpful but i still have the problem.I update the post.Maybe I wasn't careful about everything and my problem is somewhere else:\\.

Comment: @salehafzoon Are you still getting the `programing error:relation "CEA_class" already exists` error? Or is that gone and replaced with the other error? Were you able to run a migration?

Comment: yes.In migration when it says to me set default id value for column i enter just a number like 1.i think because i entered none valid id i have an error.

Comment: @salehafzoon - Undo the migration and delete it, add `null=True`: `master = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,null=True,blank=True,related_name="%(class)s_master")` and make a new migration and migrate.

Answer (score 0):

After all i came to this conclusion that the best way for deleting the Annoying irrelevant data that cause the problems is to temporary rename the model and migrate and then rename it to it's first name.By this way django itself take care of deleting relations and every data in database that causes your problem.

---

*With all these interpretations,all of the suggested answers was helpful but i think the simple is better,why not. :))*